# Entity form type in Symfony2

Tags: forms, rest, symfony, fosrestbundle

I'm trying to make a RESTFUL api and when I process `PUT`, it always responded me as

```
{
    "code": 500, 
    "message": "The form's view data is expected to be an instance of class My\\Bundle\\Entity\\Post, but is a(n) array. You can avoid this error by setting the \"data_class\" option to null or by adding a view transformer that transforms a(n) array to an instance of My\\Bundle\\Entity\\Post."
}
```

Here is how I write the `PUT` action.

```
public function putPostAction($postKey, Request $request){
    $post = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('MyBundle:Post')
        ->findPost($postKey);
    $form = $form = $this->createFormBuilder($post,
        array('data_class' => 'My\Bundle\Entity\Post'))->getForm();
    // or use createForm like
    // $form = $this->createForm(new PostType(), $post);
    $form->submit($request);
    if($form->isValid()){
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($post);
        $em->flush();
        return $post;
    }
    return array(
        "form" => $form
    );
}
```

Speaking entity type, it looks like

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('cityKey')
            ->add('status')
            ->add('text')
            ->add('imageKey')
            ->add('createTime')
            ->add('updateTime')
        ;
    }
/**
 * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
 */
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'My\Bundle\Entity\Post',
        'csrf_protection' => false
    ));
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return '';
}
```

Regarding the error message, I modified the Resolver as

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => null,
            'csrf_protection' => false
        ));
    }
```

This time I got another error,

```
{
    "code": 500, 
    "message": "EntityManager#persist() expects parameter 1 to be an entity object, array given."
}
```

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: 'findPost' function is returning an array of objects not one object. You should  call instead 'find($id)' which returns only one 'post' object.

Comment: @TurdalievNursultan YES IT WORKS! the reason why I write a `findPost($postKey)` is the select condition includes `postKey` & `enabled`, since it requires a data transformer to turn an array into an entity, alternatively  via `find($postKey)` to get the entity first then use `$post->getEnabled()` to determine next step. Save great of my time! Thanks mate.

Comment: Moved the comment to an answer so that people know this question has been already answered and accepted. Usually it's hard to know if the problem has been solved or not. Not everyone reads the comments.

Answer (score 0):

`findPost` function is returning an array of objects not an `object`. You should call instead `find($id)` which returns only one `Post` object.

So it should be:

```
$post = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()
             ->getRepository('MyBundle:Post')
             ->find($postKey);
```